# AES Limitations and MixColumns

Tags: c++, cryptography, aes

So we all agree keys are a fixed-length of 128bits or 192bits or 256bits. If our context was 50 characters in size (bytes) % 16 = 2 bytes. So we encrypt the context in 3 times, but the remaining two bytes how will they be stored in the State block. Should I pad them, the standard doesn't specify how to handle such conditions.

MixColumns stage is the most complicated aspect in the AES, however I have been unable to understand the mathematical representation. I have an understanding of the matrix multiplication, but I'm surprised of the mathematical results. Multiplying a value by 2, shift left for little endian 1 position and shift right for big endian. If we had the most significant bit was set as 1 (0x80) then we should XOR the shifted result with 0x1B. I thought by multiplying by 3 it would mean to shift the value 2 positions.

I've checked the various sources on Wikipedia, even the tutorial that provides a C implementation. But I'm more interested to complete my own implementation! Thank you for any possible input.

Comment: You need to multiply or divide by 4 to shift by two bits.

Comment: AES is only the block cipher. If you want to encrypt actual data, you have to pick a suitable _mode_, like CBC (cipher block chaining) or CTR (counter mode). CBC is a block mode, so you need to come up with some suitable way of padding (it's up to you); CTR is a stream mode so you can encrypt any number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mix columns stage the exponents are being multiplied.

```
take this example
AA*3
10101010*00000011
is
x^7+x^5+x^3+x^1*x^1+x^0
x^1+x^0 is 3 represented in polynomial form
x^7+x^5+x^3+x^1 is AA represented in polynomial form
first take x^1 and dot multiply it by the polynomial for AA.
that results in...
x^8+x^6+x^4+x^2 ... adding one to each exponent
then reduce this to 8 bits by XoRing by 11B
11B is x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+x^0 in polynomial form.
so...
x^8+x6+x^4+    x^2
x^8+   x^4+x^3+    x^1+x^0
leaves
x^6+x^3+x^2+x^1+x^0 which is AA*2
now take AA and dot multiply by x^0 (basically AA*1)
that gives you
x^7+x^5+x^3+x^1 ... a duplicate of the original value.
then exclusive or AA*2 with AA*1
x^7+    x^5+x^3+    x^1
    x^6+    x^3+x^2+x^1+x^0
which leaves
x^7+x^6+x^5+x^2+x^0 or 11100101 or E5
I hope that helps.
here also is a document detailing the specifics of how mix columns works.
```

[mix_columns.pdf](http://www.angelfire.com/biz7/atleast/mix_columns.pdf)

EDIT:Normal matrix multiplication does not apply to this ..so forget about normal matrices.

Comment: thanks man, i solved the problem for over 2 weeks. created my own polynomial multiplier (function)

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions:

1. If you want to encrypt a stream of bytes using AES, do **not** just break it into individual blocks and encrypt them individually.  This is not cryptographically secure and a clever attacker can recover a lot of information from your original plaintext.  This is called an [electronic code book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) and if you follow the link and see what happens when you use it to encrypt Tux the Linux Penguin you can visually see its insecurities.  Instead, consider using a known secure technique like [cipher-block chaining (CBC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) or [counter mode (CTR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29).  These are a bit more complex to implement, but it's well worth the effort so that you can ensure a clever attacker can't break your encryption indirectly.
2. As for how the MixColumns stage works, I really don't understand much of the operation myself.  It's based on a construction that involves fields of polynomials.  If I can find a good explanation as to how it works, I'll let you know.
3. If you want to implement AES to further your understanding, that's perfectly fine and I encourage you to do so (though you are probably better off reading the mathematical intuition as to where the algorithm comes from).  However, you should **not** use your own implementation for any actual cryptographic purposes.  Without extreme care, you will render your implementation vulnerable to a [side-channel attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack) that can compromise its security.  The most famous example of this involves RSA encryption, in which without careful planning an attacker can actually watch the power draw of the computer as it does the encryption to recover the bits of the key.  If you want to use AES to do encryption, consider using a known, tested, open-source implementation of the algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I greatly appreciated some of your input of your researched info (thanks for the heads up), but the case my own implementation would suck because of the other already mature libraries. My focus depends entirely on the degree of implementation with other existing code and functionality (ease of use), I'm programming a SSL library and part of the SSL requires block and stream ciphers which have required me to implement AES. I'm a CS graduate, but since English isn't my first language sometimes it's hard to understand the mathematical notations if the topic is barely covered. (not all the cases)

Comment: Besides I have a friend a security expert, who will also help me to test out any vulnerabilities that might be plaguing my library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the outcome of your own implementation (any internal state during computation) you can check this page :

http://www.keymolen.com/aes.jsp

It displays all internal states for any given plaintext, key and iv, also for the mixcolumns stage.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, but I already have implement AES. I also implemented my own version of DES. Which I'm currently debugging for anomalies.